# Grouping and aggregating using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a List below that needs to be grouped and aggregated using Linq method syntax.

```
| id      |Code|Descr | Number | Expiry    |
|---------|----|------|--------|-----------|
| guidId1 | A  | Desc1| Number1| 2017-03-18|
| guidId2 | A  | Desc1| Number1| 2017-03-18|
| guidId3 | B  | Desc2| Number1| 2017-03-18|
| guidId4 | B  | Desc2| Number1| 2017-03-18|
| guidId5 | C  | Desc3| Number1| 2017-03-18|
| guidId6 | A  | Desc1| Number2| 2020-05-20|
| guidId7 | A  | Desc1| Number2| 2020-05-20|
| guidId8 | A  | Desc1| Number2| 2020-05-20|
| guidId9 | B  | Desc2| Number2| 2020-05-20|
| guidId10| C  | Desc3| Number2| 2020-05-20|
| guidId11| C  | Desc3| Number2| 2020-05-20|
```

I have tried this but am not sure how to include the count:

```
myList.GroupBy(s => new { s.Number, s.Code, s.Expiry});
```

The output I want from the list:

```
{Code = "A",Descr = "Desc1",Number = "Number1",Expiry = "2017-03-18", Count = 2}
{Code = "B",Descr = "Desc2",Number = "Number1",Expiry = "2017-03-18", Count = 2}
{Code = "C",Descr = "Desc3",Number = "Number1",Expiry = "2017-03-18", Count = 1}
{Code = "A",Descr = "Desc1",Number = "Number2",Expiry = "2020-05-20", Count = 3}
{Code = "B",Descr = "Desc2",Number = "Number2",Expiry = "2020-05-20", Count = 1}
{Code = "C",Descr = "Desc3",Number = "Number2",Expiry = "2020-05-20", Count = 2}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your code (A MCVE) on [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've grouped the `Number`, `Code`, and `Expiry`, but your result needs the `Descr` as well.  You need to include that in your group, then get the count of the groups.

```
var query =
    from s in myList
    group 1 by new { s.Code, s.Descr, s.Number, s.Expiry } into g
    select new { g.Key.Code, g.Key.Descr, g.Key.Number, g.Key.Expiry, Count = g.Count() };
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This really helped.